# Why doesn’t losetup partscan work on Docker?

Tags: docker

Running following on native Ubuntu lists `loop0p1` and `loop0p2`.

```
$ losetup --find --partscan --show disk.img

$ ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0
/dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p2
```

Running same on Ubuntu Docker container only lists `loop0`.

Why?